# How To Config JwtModule.forRoot based on content of js file in the asset folder

Tags: angular, typescript

here is my app.module

```
 imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  AccordionModule.forRoot(),
  ModalModule.forRoot(),
  RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
  ButtonsModule.forRoot(),
  PaginationModule.forRoot(),
  BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
  BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
  AppRoutingModule,
  FileUploadModule,
  JwtModule.forRoot({
     config: {
       tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
       whitelistedDomains: ['http://172.20.130.27:8080'],
       blacklistedRoutes: ['http://172.20.130.27:8080/api/auth']
     }
   })
```

I want to fill whitelistedDomains based on content of external js file in Asset folder.
I cant import it (if it's extension is .ts) and require it doesnt work .
My Question is how can import js file in app.module?

Comment: You can import it the same way for js. Did you try and if gave some error?

Comment: yes, I've done. However as you may guess I've faced with error. It related to use of that variable in different place. some place needs http:// and some place does need it at all. It fixed now